# Wake up and wake

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> Hearing the noise, the boy woke.
>
> Hearing the noise, the boy woke up.

Answer (score 0):

These two sentences mean the same thing. The difference is that the first sentence is more unnaturally phrased. There is a common phrase "to wake up" which is used in the past tense in the second sentence. You could rephrase the first sentence using "awake" as the verb:

> Hearing the noise, the boy **awoke**

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/awake

Comment: The boy awoke. or: The boy woke up.

Comment: Just by curiosity I don't really get the difference between both examples that @Lambie just gave.

Comment: @Ced They are the same thing. Two ways to say the same thing.